# Can I query MongoDB by keys of a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

Suppose my collection `c` has records like this:

```
{ "_id": 1, "mydict":{"foo":..., "bar":..., "baz":..}, ...}
{ "_id": 2, "mydict":{"foo":..., "quux":..., "zot":..}, ...}
{ "_id": 3, "mydict":{"fuu":..., "quux":..., "xxx":..}, ...}
```

I want to select those records that have *any* keys from a given set, e.g., `["baz","zot"]`, have positive values in the `mydict` field.

I could write something like

```py
c.find(query={
    "$or":[
        {"mydict.baz":{"$gt":0}},
        {"mydict.zot":{"$gt":0}},
    ]})
```

but the list of keys will be much more than 2, so I would prefer something more compact (I can generate the query, of course, but this is not the point).

What if I just need to check that the keys are present in `mydict`?

Is there something like

```py
c.find(query={"$keys(mydict)":{"$intersect":["foo","bar","xxx","yyy","zzz"]}})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a simple function that converts the list of keys to a mapping of keys to wild card values. This is an example of what it would look like in Javascript(sorry I'm not a python person):

```
function mapKeys (keys) {
  const mappedKeys = keys.map(function(key) {
    return {
      // Note that I'm using the $exists here instead of $gt as
      // $exists actually checks if the field exists
      [`mydict.${key}`]: { "$exists": true }
    }
  })
  return mappedKeys;
}
```

You can then write your DB queries like this:

```
c.find(query={
    "$or": mapKeys(["foo","bar","xxx","yyy","zzz"])
})
```

Comment: Okay, so the answer is _no_. Thanks.